# iframe content from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i need to get iframe content in javascript or jquery, but main problem is that iframe src is other domain web site, how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access to the iframe if it hosted in another domain because of security. Just forget about it.

[Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871890/back-button-in-an-iframe-widget-for-an-igoogle-like-portal/2966888#2966888)

Comment: on my page there is big iframe in which user visiting other domain website. when user click button on my page i need to make screenshot of iframe contents, to do this i need full iframe html content, any ideas?

Comment: screenshot? You mean print the iframe?