# how to access content from iframe in main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How to access content from iframe in main window?

I am using an iframe to post form to different domain, and I want to access return data from the iframe which I can append to my main window.

It gives me error "access denied" when I try to access iframe elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe content from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520997/iframe-content-from-javascript)

Comment: how are you trying to access it?

Comment: @greg thanks foe your response I am accessing this way             var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

Answer (score 1):

You can't access one from the other if the `iframe` and the main page have a different domain.

You can exchange string data between the two with `window.postMessage` for modern browsers(IE8+) or using the `window.name` hack if you have to support older browsers.

Another option is to post to the other domain as you do, but giving an `id`. Then poll with a `setInterval` from the main page useing this `id` with a `JSONP` to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

If they are on different subdomains, but you have control over both domains, the solution is to add the following into a script tag:

`document.domain = 'example.com';`

Then you can chat between those iframes.

Comment: this will work if subdomains are different, eg: `sub1.domain.com` and `sub2.domain.com`, not domains.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>$("#frameDemo").contents().find("a").css("background-color","#BADA55");</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/contents/