# How can I set iframe to automatically smooth scroll to bottom when it finished loading using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to set a presentation for showing different websites. It load automatically using dynamic change of iframe URL using jQuery. But I want automatically smooth scroll iframe content to it's bottom after finish loading every websites.

My Code is

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Eximuz</title>

  </head>

<body>

<div style="height: auto"><iframe name="ifrm" id="ifrm" src="http://eximuz.com" scrolling="auto"  style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%" ></iframe>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function scroll_to_end() {
var frame = window.frames.ifrm;
var doc   = frame.document;
var node  = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].lastChild;

var y = parseInt(node.offsetTop, 10);

frame.scrollTo(0, y);
</script>
<script>

var link_arr = ['http://ibellsworld.com','http://worldarchitecturetravel.com'];
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
        var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
        if ( $iframe.length ) {
            $iframe.attr('src',url);   
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

var i = 0;
var arr_length = link_arr.length;
$('#ifrm').load(function(){

    scroll_to_end();
    setTimeout(function(){
        loadIframe('ifrm', link_arr[i]);
        if(i == link_arr.length-1){
            i = 0;
        }else{

            i++;
        }


    },4000);
});

</script>

</html>
```

It is not smooth scroll to bottom of a iframe content.How to do that?

Comment: You forgot to post the `scroll_to_end` function, that probably does the scrolling, however you generally don't have access to iframes from different origins, but scrolling the iframe window should be doable.

Comment: @adeneo, I forgot to add in question. i am now added. But that function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.
You script, cannot run any script on the page it loaded using iframe:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Related question:

[iframe content from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520997/iframe-content-from-javascript)

Same Problem: [Back button in an iframe (widget for an iGoogle-like portal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871890/back-button-in-an-iframe-widget-for-an-igoogle-like-portal/2966888#2966888)

> "...Since your widget and the page are hosted under different domains for sequre reasons you won't get access from iframe to the parent page by scripts...."

Comment: But i have loaded website dynamically. I want only to scroll to bottom when it finish loading.

Comment: To scroll the page you have to execute JavaScript on the page. You cannot execute javascript on any domain that is not your domain

Comment: Ok. Is there no option to scroll iframe content now?

Comment: The only way is to serve the page from your domain using proxy. But it is not trivial or easy task. Sorry :(   (or asking the user to press pagedown)

Comment: Or suggest any other options for presenting website not using iframe?